# How to load mongo repository to spring test application context?

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, spring-test

I have to implement some test for some spring application. I am using @SpringBootTest annotation in my test:

```
  @SpringBootTest
  @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
  class MyTest(){
  //some tests...
  }
```

It works fine, but i do not want to load all application context and and limit it by adding one or more nessecary configuration class. I done it with @ContextHierarchy:

```
 @SpringBootTest
 @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
 @ContextHierarchy(ContextConfiguration(classes = [SomeCofigClass1::class, SomeConfigClass2::class]))
  class MyTest(){
  //some tests...
  }

 //for example
 class SomeCofigClass1(){
      @Bean
      fun(someMongoRepository: SomeMongoRepository){ \\<-- Problem is here
           return SomeService(someMongoRepository)
      }
 }

 /**
  * My repository.
  */
 interface SomeMongoRepository : MongoRepository<Job, String> {}
```

Because of context is partially loaded i got a error:

```
  No qualifying bean of type 'SomeMongoRepository' available:....
```

How can i load repository in test application context?

I already tried:

1) Added @AutoConfigureDataMongo. I got error **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages**

```
 @SpringBootTest
 @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
 @ContextHierarchy(ContextConfiguration(classes = [SomeCofigClass1::class, SomeConfigClass2::class]))
 @AutoConfigureDataMongo
```

2) Replaced @SpringBootTest by @DataMongoTest. I got error **Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages**

```
 @DataMongoTest
 @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
 @ContextHierarchy(ContextConfiguration(classes = [SomeCofigClass1::class, SomeConfigClass2::class]))
```

3) With @DataMongoTest replaced @ContextHierarchy by @Import. With @Import annotation it loads all application context. This is not suit for me.

```
 @DataMongoTest
 @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
 @Import(SomeCofigClass1::class, SomeConfigClass2::class)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to load Spring's [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications) during the test.

Furthermore, classes can be selected by using the `@SpringBootTest#classes` attribute (or `@ContextConfiguration)`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeCofigClass1.class, SomeConfigClass2.class})
```

If your test makes use of inner Configuration classes, be sure to make them [static](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig) (and add `@Configuration`). From the documentation:

> If you omit the classes attribute from the @ContextConfiguration annotation, the TestContext framework tries to detect the presence of
>   default configuration classes. Specifically,
>   AnnotationConfigContextLoader and AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader
>   detect all **static nested classes** of the test class that meet the
>   requirements for configuration class implementations, as specified in
>   the @Configuration javadoc.

Comment: I use junit 5. All i need to add @ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class). My context is loaded and i can get all beans from my configuration. But if i have autowired repository bean it is not loaded in context. I must add it manually by including DataJpaTest, DataMongoTest or AutoConfigureDataMongo annotation. But it does not work and i get error that i described in question.

Comment: In spring annotation @ExtendWith included automatically.

Comment: With `@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeCofigClass1.class, SomeConfigClass2.class})` does not work. Because it is the same that `@ContextHierarchy` and framework does not try to detect presence configuration and loads only classes parameter. I got the same error **No qualifying bean of type 'SomeMongoRepository' available:....**